# Explain structure of site.categories

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

Jekyll supplies a `site.categories` variable that is accessible to liquid templates.  In my site I currently have two categories with one post each.  From looking at the jekyll bootstrap `categories.html` I know:

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
    {{ category[0] }}
```

I know this renders to the category's name.  However if I also do:

```
    {% for item in category %}
        {{ item }}
```

It seems category has two items:  its name and the post.  This makes no sense to me.  `category[0]` is `name` and then an array of posts starts at index 1?  Why does this make sense?  I wonder if this comes from Ruby somehow, but I don't know Ruby.  (Since Jekyll is written in Ruby I'm adding this tag, since I suspect much of the syntax is derivative.)

How do I determine the structure of `site.categories`?  I don't know how to debug this and don't understand liquid syntax well enough to know why this behavior makes sense.

Comment: what is so confusing to you ?? site.categories is a multidimensional array.

Comment: @sunny1304 then shouldn't I access first post as `site.categories[1][0]` instead of `site.categories[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

`site.categories` is a multi-dimensional array of categories. Each category consists of it's name as first element, and a list of posts contained in that category. The posts themselves consist of their name, content, permalink and more (the same info as in `site.posts` entries).

Comment: So it's actually the case that `cat[0]` = name, `cat[1]` = first post, etc.?  That's what it seemed like, it just seemed like a wrong design.

Comment: What problem do you have with the design? and no, cat[1] = array of posts, first post of category = cat[1][0].

Comment: So why does `cat[1]` print the post?  Does liquid just render all the contents of an array when you try to output an array?